# How to make an exactly menu bar like ministersofdesign.com?

Tags: menu, scroll

is there a way to make an exactly menubar like website www.ministersofdesign.com?
If I hover on a menu the fonts turn red, or if I scroll down to a section the menu automatically turns red font too.

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to use the ScrollTop jQuery property. And to detect what option of the menu you've to selected for each ScrollTop value, you can do that with a simple if:

**Javascript**

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() < 280) {
    $("#btn1").css({'background-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#btn2").css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    $("#btn3").css({'background-color':'#fff'});

    $("#c1").css({'border-color':'#000'});
    $("#c2").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#c3").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
}
if (($(window).scrollTop() > 280) && ($(window).scrollTop() < 450)) {
    $("#btn2").css({'background-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#btn1").css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    $("#btn3").css({'background-color':'#fff'});

    $("#c2").css({'border-color':'#000'});
    $("#c1").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#c3").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 450) {
    $("#btn3").css({'background-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#btn2").css({'background-color':'#fff'});
    $("#btn1").css({'background-color':'#fff'});

    $("#c3").css({'border-color':'#000'});
    $("#c1").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
    $("#c2").css({'border-color':'#ccc'});
}
```

Here i have a litte test I've done with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/53Run/) :)